# Infer type in interface in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have this implementation of *renderTable* function

```
interface Column<T> {
  key: keyof T,
  cellRenderer: (params: {rowData: T, cellData: any}) => void 
}

function renderTable<T>(data: T[], columns: Column<T>[]) {
    data.forEach((rowData) => {
        columns.forEach((column) => {
            const cellData = rowData[column.key]
            column.cellRenderer({rowData, cellData})
        })
    })
}

interface DataType {
  name: string,
  age: number;
}

const data: DataType[] = [
    {name: 'Anry', age: 20},
    {name: 'Brain', age: 30},
]

const columns: Column<DataType>[] = [
    {
        key: 'name',
        cellRenderer: ({cellData}) => {
            console.log('name is', cellData)
        }
    },

    {
        key: 'age',
        cellRenderer: ({cellData}) => {
            console.log('age is', cellData)
        }
    }
]

renderTable<DataType>(data, columns)
```

I want the compiler to understand that in first column cellData is **string** and in second column cellData is **number**

Is there a way to change *Column* interface to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help. changed from any to **cellData: T[keyof T]}** and Column changed from an interface to type.

```
type Column<T> = { [K in keyof T]: { 
    key: K;
    cellRenderer: (params: {rowData: T, cellData: T[K]}) => void 
   
    } 
  }[keyof T]
function renderTable<T>(data: T[], columns: Column<T>[]) {
    data.forEach((rowData) => {
        columns.forEach((column) => {
            const cellData = rowData[column.key]
            column.cellRenderer({rowData, cellData})
        })
    })
}

interface DataType {
  name: string,
  age: number;
}

const data: DataType[] = [
    {name: 'Anry', age: 20},
    {name: 'Brain', age: 30},
]

const columns: Column<DataType>[] = [
    {
        key: 'name',
        cellRenderer: ({cellData}) => {
            console.log('name is', cellData)
        }
    },

    {
        key: 'age',
        cellRenderer: ({cellData}) => {
            console.log('age is', cellData)
        }
    }
]

renderTable<DataType>(data, columns)
```

Comment: With this typings cellData will be number | string. I want infer type by key field. If key equals 'name' - cellData must be string and if key equals 'age' - cellData must be number

Comment: I updated the answer, you need to define Column as type. Please take a look and let me know.

Comment: This is what I need. Thank you!

Comment: Please mark this as answer, it will help others.

Comment: @Sam `{ [K in keyof T]: {}}[keyof T]` - amazing workaround. Thanks!